# sdcard and tablet encryption WINDOWS 10

Tags: security, encryption, windows-10, sd-card, password-protection

I am looking for a smart way to encrypt my HD and SD card on my Windows 10 Tablet. I want the SD card to stay always in this device. I have strict confidence files on this card so I have to encrypt it for the case of loss or thievery!
Is there a smart way to protect my data without the need of re-entering a password every device-wake-up?

Answer (score 0):

You may use some encrypt methods such as MD5 , SHA1 ,SHA256 and so on to encrypt your data . Here is a video about "Creating an MD5 Hash and Calling the API" , look [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhDW8KinN3w) . You may also learn from official documents , just click [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographichash.aspx) , I hope these may help you!